# how to get json data in a list with link

Tags: php, mysql, html

Hi i am able to get json data as a list in html page but i like to get as a list of link. Because when i click on the link it will show details.

What i have done in `tenantlistmob.php`

```
<?php 
include('connection.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tenanttemp");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
$array[] = array($row['TenantFirstName']);
}
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Then my html page is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jasmine-device_2/styles/main.css" />
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery.getJSON("tenantlistmob.php", function (jsonData) {

            jsonData= eval(jsonData);//get json array

            for (i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++)//iterate over all options
            {
              for ( key in jsonData[i] )//get key => value
              { 
             $("#getname").append($("<li></li>").html(jsonData[i][key]), document.all ? i : null);
              }
            }

});

 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="index">
<div id="getname"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is

```
 Humayun
 Sahjahan
 Bayezid
 Bayezid
 Asaduzzaman
 Mouri
```

I am getting the `TenantFirstName` as a list.But i like to get it as a list of link.Because when i click on a name it will show details of that name. How can i do both work(as a list of link and when click on a link it will show details in a html page query from mysql database)?
Please help.

Comment: do console.log and paste the output here for better answer

Comment: You are simply adding data in li, add anchor tag in your <li>

Comment: @MianKhurramIjaz i placed the output.give me suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use table like below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jasmine-device_2/styles/main.css" />
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery.getJSON("tenantlistmob.php", function (jsonData) {

           $("#user_spec").html("");//clear old options

            jsonData= eval(jsonData);//get json array

            for (i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++)//iterate over all options
            {
              for ( key in jsonData[i] )//get key => value
              { 
                    //$("#user_spec").get(0).add(new Option(jsonData[i][key],[key]), document.all ? i : null);
                    //$("#getname tbody").append($("<li></li>").html(jsonData[i][key]), document.all ? i : null);
                    var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + "<a href='#'>" + jsonData[i][key] + "</a>" + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                    $(tblRow).appendTo("#getname tbody");
              }
            }

  });

 });
 </script></head>
 <body>
 <form name="index">
 <div>
 <table id="getname" border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
    </thead>
  <tbody>

   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you.But how can i get a link regarding this.